# How to use a named template as a YAML list element in a helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I would like to use a named template as an element of a YAML list.

For example:

I would like to use the following template

```yaml
{{- define "mytemplate" -}}
name: foo
value: bar
details: baz
{{- end -}}
```

as an element of the `evenmore` list:

```yaml
some:
  more:
    evenmore:
      - name: foo
        value: bar
        details: baz
```

I tried treating `mytemplate` explicitly as a list element by changing it to:

```yaml
{{- define "mytemplate" -}}
- name: foo
  value: bar
  details: baz
{{- end -}}
```

However, this approach is unusable if I want to use the `merge` function on `mytemplate` and some other named template.

I have also tried using the `list` function:

```yaml
spec:
  more:
    evenmore:
      {{- include "mytemplate" . | list | toYaml | indent 6 }}
```

Based on minor modifications, this would leave me with either multiline string as the list element or mismatched indentation for the top field of the list element.

Is there a way to use a named template as a list element without modifying the named template to be a list element itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```yaml
some:
  more:
    evenmore:
      - {{ include "mytemplate" . | indent 8 | trim }}
```

Breaking apart that last line:

1. Invoke `mytemplate`, using the current context as the parameter, but using the Helm [`include`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function) function to get its output as a string.
2. Indent every line (including the first line) by 8 spaces.
3. Trim off the leading and trailing whitespace; remove the indentation from the first line.

So the first line in the template output (the `name:`) will appear immediately after the hyphen-space YAML list-item marker; and the remaining lines (`value:` and `details:`) will be indented 8 spaces, where the number 8 is carefully chosen so they line up in the output.